# How to fix weird styling using Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have an issue with the [Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) as shown in the picture below. I've done everything in the documentation and the console is blank without errors.

[image]

[image]

I've included the following assets:

```
<link href='/assets/plugins/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css' />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/nb.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#event_title').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'nb'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-relative">
  <label>Tittel på arrangement</label>
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="event_title" name="event_title" placeholder="Tittel på arrangement">
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap is included in the header. I even checked if my custom CSS is interfering with Datetimepicker, but I removed all my custom CSS to check if that's the case. I had the same problem without my custom styling. I'm using Bootstrap 3.

What could be the case?

Comment: Try with include bootstrap-theme.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Installation Guides](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#installation-guides) section of the docs:

> Include necessary scripts and styles:
>
> ```
> <head>
>   <!-- ... -->
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
> </head>
> ```

Since you are using Bootstrap style (*Bootstrap is included in the header.*) you have to use `bootstrap-datetimepicker.css` instead of `bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css`.

Here a working snippet (using resources from CDN):

```js
$('#event_title').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'nb'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/nb.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group form-group-relative">
  <label>Tittel på arrangement</label>
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="event_title" name="event_title" placeholder="Tittel på arrangement">
  </div>
</div>
```